# how to apply Calculate function with two filters in DAX to get the Running Sum

Tags: excel, dax

I would like to get the running sum of `[Days Past Due]` Column grouped by project number and for each project number, get the value for each phase/end date. 
IN SQL I would do:

```
SELECT   Project_number
         ,phase
         ,Sum(Days Past Due) RunningTotal
FROM     Table

GROUP BY Project_number
         ,phase
ORDER BY Project_number
         ,phase
```

I would do something similar in DAX please.

I try that:

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( DataSource[Days Past Due] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( DataSource, DataSource[Project Number] )
)
```

It gives me the total for each project number repeated in the 4 rows. That's not what I want exactly. I need to apply a second filter on that.

Please look at the attachment, it has the last column with the desired output.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Check these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226792, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072341, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275270. You may find more by searching `[dax] running total`

Comment: Thanks Alexis for your suggestion. I have seen countless examples of that nature before I posted this question. The issue is that I can't apply two filters, I wanna say - in DAX language - Group by project number, then within each project, group by either phase of end date so I can get the running sum for each row and the one above it. and it has to reset at the beginning of each risk. I ve been struggling  with that for almost a week now. Still not working.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. You can pass as many filters as you like inside the `CALCULATE` function.

Comment: Like if I do this:=CALCULATE(SUM(DataSource[Days Past Due]), FILTER(ALL(DataSource), DataSource[End Date] <= MAX(DataSource[End Date])), DataSource[Project Number])   .. As you can see. There is two filters, but it doesn't take them. The output is not giving the right result.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your attempt like this:

```
Cumulative Days Past Due = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM( DataSource[Days Past Due] ),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT( DataSource, DataSource[Project Number] ),
        DataSource[End Date] <= MAX( DataSource[End Date] )
    )
)
```

Note that you can include more filtering conditions in the `FILTER` function by joining more conditions with `&&`. You can add more filter conditions inside `CALCULATE` as well. Here's an example:

```
Cumulative Days Past Due = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM( DataSource[Days Past Due] ),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT( DataSource, DataSource[Project Number] ),
        DataSource[End Date] <= MAX( DataSource[End Date] )
            && DataSource[Start Date] > DATE( 2018, 12, 31 )
    ),
    DataSource[Phase] = "Scope"
)
```

---

The documentation for `CALCULATE` and `FILTER` might be useful for further clarification:

https://dax.guide/calculate/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax

https://dax.guide/filter/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/filter-function-dax

---

If you are trying to write this formula in a calculated column, it will not work as expected and you will need to use `EARLIER` instead of `MAX`:

```
Cumulative Days Past Due = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM( DataSource[Days Past Due] ),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT( DataSource, DataSource[Project Number] ),
        DataSource[End Date] <= EARLIER( DataSource[End Date] )
    )
)
```

The reason for this is that in a measure `MAX` is calculated within its local filter context but in a calculated column the context is different and you use `EARLIER` to refer to the earlier row context, that is, the `End Date` in the current row of the larger table (rather than the smaller `FILTER` table).

If you want something that works either as a measure or a calculated column, then @RADO's solution is pretty close and you can write this:

```
Cumulative Days Past Due =
VAR CurrDate =
    CALCULATE( MAX( DataSource[Start Date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM( DataSource[Days Past Due] ),
        ALLEXCEPT( DataSource, DataSource[Project Number] ),
        DataSource[End Date] <= CurrDate
    )
```

In this version, the `MAX` works just as it did before in the first version above and it should also work in a calculated measure because wrapping the `MAX` in a `CALCULATE` performs a context transition that transforms the row context into a filter context corresponding to that single row.

You can drop the `CALCULATE` wrapper for just a measure and drop both the `CALCULATE` and `MAX` functions for a simpler calculated column. In either of these cases, this variable version is likely the more performant one since the `ALLEXCEPT` function is optimized to work efficiently within `CALCULATE` rather than having to instantiate a new table when using `FILTER`.

---

For further details on cumulative totals, I recommend DAX Patterns as a resource:

https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I tried both suggestions and same issue: I get the total of 4 rows for each project Number repeated for each phase. (I took a screenshot but no way to attach it here) . Looking at the example above in the post: for first risk, it says 7 for all 4 rows, and 10 for all 4 following rows. It's not giving the running sum.

Comment: Are you doing it as a calculated column? If so, then use EARLIER instead of MAX. I wrote the above as a measure instead.

Comment: Yeaaaayyyy, I did earlier function and got the expected result. This is the final function: =CALCULATE(SUM(DataSource[Days Past Due]), FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(DataSource, DataSource[Project Number]), DataSource[End Date] <= EARLIER(DataSource[End Date])))