# DAX code for cumulative sum (in a column)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am working on a project, where a column needs cumulative summing. How do I find the cumulative sum for a column and store in another column.?

I expect the output as shown:

[image: columnar image suggesting the query and output required]

Comment: Cumulative based on what index? What DAX code have you tried so far?

Comment: This recent question and the other questions that are linked should give you a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55819431/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a date table and are using that to calculate you running total; you could follow the DAX pattern provided below or just amend it to fit your needs:

```
CumSum :=
VAR MaxDate =
    MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[A] ), 'Date'[Date] <= Maxdate, ALL ( date ) )
```